# Retrieve value from a oid type in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

How to retrieve values from an oid column type in PostgreSQL This table is generated by an application and not by the user, and as per the documentation of the product, it says that it stores transaction data in binary format. When I browse through the data, it has a maximum length of 6 or 7, but when I configure the product with another database, like H2, I can see more data stored in the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you seem to be using [large objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html). You shouldn't be doing that, but use `bytea` instead, which would behave as you expect. Large objects are a legacy feature that is likely to cause all kinds of trouble for you.

You have to open an read the large object with that `oid` explicitly.